# JS errors while running angular app on IE9

Tags: javascript, angularjs, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-9

My Angular app runs fine on IE11, but I need to make it compatible with IE9. Thus I have included these polyfills :

```
<script src="polyfills/matchMedia.js"></script>
<script src="polyfills/polyfill.js"></script>
<script src="polyfills/esClassList.js"></script>
<script src="polyfills/classList.min.js"></script>
<script src="polyfills/Blob.js"></script>
<script src="polyfills/typedarray.js"></script>
<script src="polyfills/formdata.js"></script>
```

but still i am getting this error

[image: Error Image]

But from the error I am unable to understand which line of code is causing the trouble, also which other polyfills needs to be included to make `$http.get`make work in IE9.

I am trying to fetch a JSON Array through `$http.get` using the following code :

```
$http.get('GetDataUrl.php').success(function(data){
    var el = document.createElement( 'span' );
    el.innerHTML = data;
    $scope.MyData = JSON.parse(el.childNodes[28].innerHTML)["0"];           
});
```

Comment: I have no idea how your directory structure is. For IE you need all the core-js ES6 polyfills.

Comment: Have you tried to use $q - https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$q

Comment: Try replacing .success with .then

Comment: @TatsuyukiIshi i googled and go this folder https://github.com/zloirock/core-js/tree/master/es6 but i need to know how can i include it in my app